# How do I calculate the final temperature of three reacting objects that have reached thermal equilibrium?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am trying to solve the following heat transfer problem and am finding my current knowledge deficient for setting up my equations correctly:

"You drop a 283-g silver figure of a polar bear into the 233-g aluminum cup of a well-insulated calorimeter containing 255 g of liquid water at 24.7°C. The bear\'s initial temperature is 98.1°C. What is the final temperature of the water, cup, and bear when they reach thermal equilibrium? The specific heats of silver, aluminum, and liquid water are, respectively, 234 J/(kg·K), 910 J/(kg·K), and 4190 J/(kg·K)."

All the heat transfer questions in my practice homework involved the reaction of just two substances, one of which would be losing heat and the other of which would be gaining heat. The equation usually took the form:

Q gained                                = - Q lost

Lv(M1)                                  =   -M2(C2)(delta T)

latent heat of vaporization (or fusion) x mass of substance  =  - mass of substance x specific heat of substance x change in temperature.

Since this formula is designed to be used when only two substances are present, I am not sure how to apply the concept to this new situation.

Also, I am having trouble figuring out how to convert the specific heats from J/(kg K) to J/(kg C), which be necessary if I want my final answer in degrees Celsius.

Thanks in advance for your help with this problem that has been troubling me for way too long!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Generalize to the sum of energy losses (or energy gains; it doesn't matter as long as you're consistent) of all the components in this closed system remaining zero:

$$E_\mathrm{lost,\,1}+E_\mathrm{lost,\,2}+E_\mathrm{lost,\,3}=0.$$

Your first equation (which has a sign error) essentially says the same thing but for two components and with one term brought to the other side.

Then, express each energy change in terms of a temperature change using the heat capacity.

2. A material property expressed in terms of something per degree Celsius is numerically equivalent to expressing it in terms of something per kelvin. That is, we're dealing with a temperature change rather than an absolute temperature, and the intervals of °C and K are identical.

Comment: Thanks so much for your very helpful answer! However, I still have some more questions about how to set this all up. If the formula for heat transfer (which my course represents with a "Q") is Q = MC(deltaT), or mass x specific heat x change in temperature, and yet I don't know how much the temperature of each substance ultimately changes, how can I calculate any further? I know that delta T can also be expressed as TH-TC, or the hot temperature minus the cold temperature, but with no knowledge of the final temperature, nothing here seems workable. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you use the dummy variable $T_\mathrm{final}$ for the uniform final temperature, don't you end up with one equation in one unknown?

Comment: I have how tried several times to work the problem with Tfinal as the dummy variable. For the Q of the silver bear, I listed TH - TC as (98.1 Celsius - Tfinal), since I figured the bear will cool down when placed in the cool water, makiing its Tfinal lower than its Tinitial. For both the aluminum and the water, I assumed they were both at a TC of 24.7 Celsius and listed TH - TC for both of them as (Tfinal - 24.7 Celsius), since their final temp after the reaction would be higher than 24.7 Celsius. When I plugged in all the values and moved the unknowns to the right hand side, I got

Comment: -25131.4778 = -1214.258 Tfinal, which divides out to Tfinal = 20.697 Celsius. This is clearly not the correct answer, because it shows a final equilibrium temperature that is lower than the coldest original temperature in the reaction (24.7 Celsius). What am I doing wrong here? Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: You have a sign error. You don't need to think about what's heating up or cooling down; just write each temperature change as $T_1-T_\mathrm{final}$, $T_2-T_\mathrm{final}$, and $T_3-T_\mathrm{final}$. The signs will take care of themselves. I get 28.309°C (nonsignificant digits included just to compare answers).

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! I have gotten the same answer and I finally understand how to set up problems similar to this one in the future. Keep up the good work!